# Linux kernel git tree - version.h is not refreshed

Tags: git, linux-kernel

I'm compiling a kernel module and realized the include/linux/version.h is not refresh despite I checkout the new kernel from git and ran make modules_prepare. I also tried to remove include/linux/version.h, but it's not regenerate when I run make modules_prepare.

Any idea how can I get an up to date version.h?

Comment: May be its included in the `.gitignore` file ? `grep` for this file name.

Comment: I checked .gitignore, it did not ignore include/linux dir

Answer (score -1):

I copied include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h to include/linux/version.h and that seem to work. However, I'm still looking for more formal way of updating this file.

Comment: Why is there a downvote? I would like an explanation?

Comment: *1.* coping an auto-generated file usually is not a good thing. The next time you generate the file could be different. It is better a symlink. *2.* this is not a portable solution. _It is not correct to ask user application to change path_, but it is worst to ask the user to configure their machine (in this case coping/linking files) as the application pretend. *3.* this is not an answer is an hack for buggy applications (e.g. vmware player, catalyst driver, realtek audio, ...). If you can patch your application look for both the path so it will work on old and new kernels.

Comment: When running make in the kernel folder, it ran CHK for include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h. Honestly, I think the makefile just needs to do a symbolic link automatically to include/linux/version.h as you suggest. Still not sure why that file is neither tracked nor auto refreshed.

Answer (score -1):

Since I do not remember which kernel version, `version.h` header is located in

```
include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h
```

So, whatever you want to do with this file, use the one in the correct location. Some "*old*" programs still assume that the file is in `include/linux/version.h`

You can add to your Makefile new header directory:

```
-I/path/to/kernel/src/include/generated/uapi/
```

So your user application still use `#include <linux/version.h>`

(I'm supposing that you are using gcc, maybe on other compiler the option is not `-I`)

Comment: This is not correct to ask user application to change the include path, because i checked header folder in the deb package, include/generated folder is not there.

Comment: and `include/linux/version.h` too. The new position for that file is in the answer. If you do not want to update your application, you can create a symlink (not a copy as you suggested); but this is not a solution. About the correctness. With that idea of "correct" we still stuck with API from the '60 :) That file was moved a couple of years ago.

Comment: Are you suggesting instead of #include <linux/version.h>, the user should write #include <generated/uapi/linux/version.h> ?